# load json files in google cloud storage into big query table

Tags: json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to do it with client lib using python.

the problem I am facing is that the TIMESTAMP on the JSON files are on Unix epoch TIMESTAMP format and big query can't detect that:

according to documentation:

[image]

so I wonder what to do?

I thought about changing the JSON format manually before I load it into BigQuery table?

Or maybe looking for an auto conversion from the BigQuery side?

I wondered across the internet and could not find anything useful yet.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 solutions

- Either you update the format before the BigQuery integration
- Or you update the format after the BigQuery integration

**Before**

Before means updating your JSON (manually or by script) or to update it by the process that load the JSON into BigQuery (like Dataflow).

I personally don't like this, file handling are never funny and efficient.

**After**

In this case, you let BigQuery loading your JSON file into a temporary table and convert your UNIX timestamp into a Number or a String. Then, perform a request into this temporary table, convert the field in the correct timestamp format, and insert the data in the final table.

This way is smoother and easier (a simple SQL query to write). However, it implies cost to read all the loaded data (to write them then)

Comment: Hi sir, first thanks, I just thought about same thing doing "INSERT SELECT" from temp table into the new one.

Comment: the thing is that I need to query all table and cast only 1 column how do I do that?

Comment: something like this `SELECT * EXCEPT (timestamp_field), CAST(....) AS timestamp_field FROM temp_table`